# Jquery localstorage checkbox

Tags: jquery

I'm new in jquery and I was wondering if you could help me. I'm setting up a webpage that imports top 100 imdb list from .json file and also details from another .json file. I've manage to do that but I'm in difficulty to use local storage with all my checkboxes. I want to be able to store what movies I've seen by clicking on checkbox and I want the page to remember when I it again. 
I'm also new to stackoverflow so I hope I'm doing this right.

Here's my jquery code so far!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON('movies.json', function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(index, movie){
            $.getJSON('details/' + movie.id + '.json', function(details) {

                $('#movies').append("<div class='movie' id='" + movie.id +"'>" +
                '<p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id='+ movie.id + ' name="myCheckbox"/> <p id=' 
                + movie.id + '><p class="movietitle" id ='+ movie.id +'>'+ movie.title +'</p></p></p>' +

                        "<div class='info' id='" + movie.id +"'>" +
                            '<p> Country:' + details.country + '</p>' +     
                            '<p> Year:' + details.year + '</p>' + 
                            '<p> Rating:' + details.rating + '</p>' +
                            '<p> Languages:' + details.languages + '</p>' +
                            '<p> Rating:' + details.rating + '</p>' +
                            '<a class="imdb" href =" '+ details.imdburl + ' ">Skoðaðu myndina á imdb</a>' + 
                        "</div>" +  
                    "</div>"
                    );
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I realized the bit you probably wanted the most was retaining the checked boxes, so I added that bit of code in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, had to rewrite this after reading and realized I was wrong about a point and could simplify this. You're almost there, but instead of id='movie.id' (or in a addition to) to make it easier, that should be value='movie.id'.

So:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value='+ movie.id + ' name="myCheckbox"/>
```

If you want to get the array of values anytime something is checked/unchecked and then store it:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){

 var movieIDs = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
   return $(this).val();
}).get();

 localStorage['movieList'] = JSON.stringify(movieIDs);

});
```

and then when you want to retrieve:

```
var movieList = JSON.parse(localStorage["movieList"]);
```

For instance, to show the checked/viewed movies on load:

```
var movieList = (localStorage["movieList"]) ? JSON.parse(localStorage["movieList"]) : [];

$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
    if($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), movieList) >= 0)
    {
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    }           
});
```

See the JSFiddle here (UPDATED): http://jsfiddle.net/thespacebean/SdcLr/5/

Now if you reload the page, your former choices will still be showing.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time in this but i cant get it to work my code is in an answer below.